# How to save and load random number generator state in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, random-seed, reproducible-research

I am training a DL model in Pytorch, and want to train my model in a deterministic way.
As written in [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) official guide, I set random seeds like this:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
torch.manual_seed(0)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

Now, my training is long and i want to save, then later load everything, including the RNGs. I use `torch.save` and `torch.load_state_dict` for the model and the optimizer.

How can the random number generators be saved & loaded?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`torch.get_rng_state`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.get_rng_state) and  [`torch.set_rng_state`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_rng_state)

When calling `torch.get_rng_state` you will get your random number generator state as a torch.ByteTensor.

You can then save this tensor somewhere in a file and later you can load and use `torch.set_rng_state` to set the random number generator state.

---

*When using `numpy` you can of course do the same there using:

[`numpy.random.get_state`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.get_state.html#numpy.random.get_state) and [`numpy.random.set_state`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.set_state.html#numpy.random.set_state)*

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to do the same with the Numpy RNG?

Comment: There's also a context manager now, https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/random.html#torch.random.fork_rng. Viewing the source seems to suggest that `get/set_rng_state` is only for the cpu device.